# Understanding how to dismiss a UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm a bit confused, this isn't a question on how to dismiss a UIImagePickerController, it's more of a "why did that work" type of question. I am working in iOS7.

Looking online at the apple documentation (this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW6), I came across the following code for dismissing a UIImagePickerController:

```
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Edit: I know that that method was deprecated, so instead I tried the following, and that did not work either:

```
[[picker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Those didn't work for me. This however did work:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

- Is the apple documentation wrong? or just outdated?
- Why does the second bit of code work, because from my understanding, its the parent view controllers job to dismiss something like a popover or in this case a UIImagePickerController

Thank you.

Edit: This is how I am presenting the UIImagePickerController, the UITapGestureRecognizer calls the first method which then calls the second.

```
- (IBAction)captureMoment:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self startCameraCaptureFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)startCameraCaptureFromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
                               usingDelegate:(id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>)delegate {

    if (delegate == nil || controller == nil || [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) {
        return NO;
    }

    UIImagePickerController *camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    camera.allowsEditing = NO;

    camera.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentViewController:camera animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you post how you are presenting the picker?

Comment: I just edited the question and pasted the code there

Comment: You probably want `picker.presentingViewController`, not `picker.parentViewController`.

Comment: rmaddy's suggestion worked, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 methods that worked for me

1. Use `picker.presentingViewController` instead of `picker.parentViewController`, answer by rmaddy
2. Use the following code in the `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:`, `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];`

Here is the code in its entirety, this is placed in the UIViewController that presents the UIImagePickerController:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` has been deprecated since iOS6. The new method you are using is the correct one.

Comment: I tried the new method as well (check the first edit in the question), and it still did not work

Comment: You should call this method from the viewcontroller that presented the UIImagePickerController modally.